# Is there any alternative to get_queryset() method to capture query parameter in Django ViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets, drf-queryset

what i am using is :

```
class SomethingViewSet(viewset.ModelviewSet):
 def get_queryset(self):
     id=self.request.query_params.get('id')
```

Is there any alternative to capture query params.

Comment: You don't need `get_queryset` for that. You can obtain these in any method (since these are simply wrapped in the `self.request` object).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and for the url parameter?

Comment: The `self.request.kwargs` dictionary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  limit=self.request['limit']   TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable    I am getting this error.

Comment: it is `self.request.kwargs['limit']`

Comment: i am overriding list(self, request, *args, **kwargs) method          this time getting this error : AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'kwargs'